# Connect localhost Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I just installed for the first time Postgres on my computer and I was able to connect my database through JetBrains DataGrip.

but when I am trying to connect the database through my app (using gorm) it doesn't work...

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

and i did try to connect this way:

```
postgresql://postgres:12qwaszx@localhost:5432/postgres
```

and this way:

```
db, _ := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres password=12qwaszx")
```

this is how I connect to the db:

```
db, _ := gorm.Open("postgres", app.Config.DSN)
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" usually is not enough information for people to help you with your question, and can you post some sample code of where "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @nijmI sorry, but I don't know how to give more information about this issue.

Comment: Start with the error you are getting and your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You did import `github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres`?

Comment: @nijm the error I get is just: (sql: database is closed), i don't have more information about the issue. and yes i did import it

Comment: When are you getting the error `sql: database is closed`? Is it returned from `Open` or are you getting it later when using `db`?

Comment: It seems like you might be closing your db after successfully opening it, can you show the code surrounding your gorm.Open call? For example if you're using defer to close your db, but you're doing that inside a function that's not main then your db will be closed after that function exits and anything that tries to use the db after that will get the error you're getting.

Comment: @mkopriva I don't close the connection, when I am using a database that host on the internet its works. but when I am trying to use the localhost database I get this issue. about showing my code here, there is nothing to show. just a simple connection to database using gorm

Comment: @NirBerko fair enough but still the question remains where from exactly are you getting this error? Is it from `gorm.Open`? or are you getting it when you're using `db` trying to execute some specific query? If it's from using `db` are you getting the error right the first time you use the `db` or are some calls going through but then later you get the error?

Comment: @mkopriva i am getting this error from gorm Open. i think this issue coming from the postgress server and not from go. maybe i need to define settings to be able to use the database, but the strange thing that i was able to connect the database from jetbrains datagrip

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#PostgreSQL), you should connect to PostgreSQL like this:

```
import (
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

func main() {
  db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=myhost port=myport user=gorm dbname=gorm password=mypassword")
  defer db.Close()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I also tried this way, I will add it to the question.

Comment: In your example, you didn't check for errors. In Go, always check for errors.

Comment: @peterSO the error i get is: sql: database is closed, so i have problem with solving this issue without too much information. maybe someone know this isuue